# How to get connectionstrings for SQL and Redis from Azure Key Vault?

Tags: security, azure

I am trying to understand if it is ever possible for Sitecore to load connection strings values from Azure Key Vault, not from web.config (or ConnectionStrings.config) file?

Comment: maybe this info can help you: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/440060

Comment: More like this: https://docs.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#connection-strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get those at runtime by default with Sitecore OOTB.
But like Mark Cassidy mentioned in a comment above, you could leverage this https://docs.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#connection-strings if you are hosting Sitecore on Azure Web App (you could set them in your ARM Templates, from within the Azure portal or by PowerShell/CLI commands).

Regarding Azure Key Vault, what you could do is to store your secrets in it and use them during the PowerShell/ARM Templates deployment. One example of using this at deployment time could be found here: https://alwaysupalwayson.blogspot.ca/2017/03/advanced-sitecore-arm-templates.html. It was a POC, experimental and one year ago, but in case it could help.